# using different tenses in different parts of the system

Tags: labels, wording, graphs

in one part of the system where the user creates forecast legend of the graph displays "forecast".

In another section of the system where a user uses the forecasting graph (but essentially it's the same data) the legend is "forecasted".

How strict should consistency be so that it will use the same tense in both parts of the system? Is it OK to use different tenses in different parts according to context?

Answer (score 2):

In this example it appears that forecast is done to create (current tense) and forecasted (past tense) is for something that has already been created.

Seems like it is consistent.